# Finding Reference Audio Signal in Test Audio Signal and Cropping Accordingly

Tags: matlab, python, signal-detection, audio-processing, matched-filter

As seen in the diagram, below I have a reference audio and a test audio. I want to find at what part of the test clip the reference audio be heard. Once, that is found I want to crop the test file from the point where the match begins and the point where the match ends. How can I do this **matching** and **cropping** of audio signals using **Python**? Some code will be of help.

The diagram below(from wiki) is for illustration purposes only[image]

My audio clips:
Reference audio:  [africaChirp](https://vocaroo.com/i/s15CM6Se8GiZ)
Test audio:       [Africa](https://www.ee.columbia.edu/%7Edpwe/sounds/music/africa-toto.wav)

I want to find the time in seconds at which africaChirp appears in Africa. africaChirp was cropped from the source file, Africa, found in [Dan Ellis: Music - Original and Synthetic](https://www.ee.columbia.edu/%7Edpwe/sounds/music/).

I have also included my code to show my progress:

```
import numpy as np
import logging
from scipy.io import wavfile

rate2,test = wavfile.read('africa.wav')

#indices
testStart  = 6000;
testEnd    = 200000;
refStart   = testStart + 11000;
refEnd     = refStart + 2000 - 1;

testSig=test[testStart:testEnd]
refSig=test[refStart:refEnd]

refStartRel=refStart-testStart+1
refEndRel=refEnd-testStart+1
no_samples_test=testSig.shape[0]
no_samples_ref=refSig.shape[0]

xcorr=np.zeros((no_samples_test-no_samples_ref+1,1))
xcorr_norr=np.zeros((no_samples_test-no_samples_ref+1,1))

refSig_norm= np.linalg.norm(refSig)
for i in range(1,xcorr.shape[0]):
    testSig_samples=testSig[i:(i+no_samples_ref)]
    xcorr[i]=np.sum(np.multiply(testSig_samples,refSig))
    linalgnorm=np.linalg.norm(testSig_samples)
    xcorr_norr[i]=xcorr[i]/np.multiply(refSig_norm,linalgnorm)
    
xcorr_max_id=np.max(np.abs(xcorr_norr))
print(xcorr_max_id)
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you have a reference signal you want to find in a different signal then your model matches almost perfectly (Up to the environment the signal to be found is in) to [Matched Filter](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Matched_filter).

So basically you need to do cross correlation between the Test Signal and the Reference Signal.
Find the point of maximum correlation and create a cropping zone around it according to the length of the reference signal.

### Update

I downloaded the files and wrote a MATLAB Code to do the task of finding a reference signal within a signal.
I generated an equivalent test case by cropping 14,000 samples from the Song File - *Toto - Africa* as the **Test Signal** and from them cropped 2,000 samples as the **Reference Signal**.

Matched Filter in the case above must be tweaked to normalize different volume levels in the signal.
Hence the correct way to so is Matched Filter which is normalized by the Norm of the sections being cross correlated (This is actually correlation in Statistics).

The the result it as following:

[image]

As can be seen, the algorithm detects the exact starting index of the reference signal.
Pay attention that the classic cross correlation yields the wrong answer as it is being tricked by higher volume levels of the test signal.
When we take care of different volume level by the normalization then the maximum correlation happens exactly where it should.

The MATLAB code is available at my [Signal Processing StackExchange Question 50003 - GitHub Repository](https://github.com/RoyiAvital/StackExchangeCodes) (Look at the `SignalProcessing\50003` folder).

Comment: I have tried doing that but my program crops a part which is completely unrelated to the reference audio. Can I show you my code?

Comment: You better share the test signal and the reference signal.

Comment: I have added them. Please let me know how you can do it and provide some code if possible. Thanks

Comment: Where does `Africa Chirp` come from? Is it part of `Africa` or is it some kind of processed part of it?

Comment: it is directly taken from Africa. no processing done.

Comment: Could you point from where? Just as a reference?

Comment: africaChirp starts at 31st second of africa

Comment: Would you mind if I cut Africa into 15 [Sec] audio file and cut 3 seconds from it and use that to show how to work? It is just hard to show something on ~6,000,000 samples.

Comment: yes sure, just send me a link of the cut files after you have managed to do the cropping

Comment: Hi, were you able to get any results?

Comment: Hopefully I will do a small demo code at weekend.

Comment: @listener, I added code and test case to show you how it works. I think now it is fully answered.

Comment: Thank you very much for your help. I translated your code into python. However, it does not work. Could you help me check what is the error? My code is the qn above itself. Thanks

Comment: I think you should use `np.argmax` to get the index. We are after the index, not the value. Please mark the question as answered.

Comment: changed to argmax. Got the index as 8650. I tried to crop the file from 8650 to 60000. It was about 2 seconds. But it was completely silent. maybe you can try and run my code and see if it works for you

Comment: @listener, I'm sorry. I don't have Python. You can try this on Octave.

Comment: @listener, Have a look at - https://repl.it/@RoyiAvital/StackExchange-Signal-Processing-Q50003.

Answer (score 1):

since the reference signal used in the cross-correlation is fixed in amplitude, but the test signal is not (it can be loud or quiet), perhaps you need to also run an envelope follower after the test signal (maybe r.m.s.) and then divide the result of the sliding cross-correlation with the value of the envelope.

because, even if there is no reference in that loud portion of the test signal, cross-correlating against it will still yield large values, not because of correlation, but just because one of the inputs was loud.

also you might want to look up **"matched filter"** which is essentially a sliding cross-correlation.  let the impulse response of an FIR be a time-reversed copy of your reference signal.  then run the test signal through that and divide the output of the FIR filter by the envelope of the test signal to normalize the output.  then you should see the highest amplitudes when the reference signal appears.