# How to Find Shift Between Two Signals with Cross Correlation?

Tags: matlab, signal-detection, cross-correlation

I have calculated the cross-correlation function between to waveforms. I would like to find the shift between the two waveforms from the peak of the cross-correlation function. I am not really sure how to do that precisely. In this example, I have shifted signal 2 by 1000 Angstroms with respect to signal 1. I want to recover this shift from the CCF.[image: Signal 1][image: Signal 2][image: CCF]

Comment: You seem to have the wrong units in the cross correlation horizontal axis. It should be the same units as with the signals.

Comment: Could you please mark my answer? Or address what is missing? Thank You.

Answer (score 0):

Well, All in there is a simple play with the indices of the Auto Correlation Function.

Have a look at my solution for [Finding Reference Audio Signal in Test Audio Signal and Cropping Accordingly](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/a/50005/128).
You'll find there full MATLAB Code for the task you mention.

Enjoy...